# Python Loop Exercise

Tags: python-2.7, loops

Thanks for taking the time to review my question. I'm working on an exercise and just can't seem to figure out (once more) what I'm doing wrong. Here is the original question/exercise:
This program is supposed to display every fifth year starting with 2015; that is, 2015, 2020, 2025, and so on, for 30 years.

Basically, in Python, I need to build a program that displays every fifth year from 2015 to 2045. I've built the following code:

```
atart_year = 2015
factor = 5
end_year = 2045
EOFNAME = '9999'
print 'Enter year or', EOFNAME,'to quit'
year = input('')

while year != end_year:
    for year in range(2015,2046):
        final_year = year + factor
        print final_year 

    print 'The End'

    print

    print 'Enter year or', EOFNAME,'to quit'
    year = input('')
```

When I run this, Python spits out the following numbers (not in factors of 5):
2015
2020
2021
2022
2023
2024
2025
2026
2027
2028
2029
2030
2031
2032
2033
2034
2035
2036
2037
2038
2039
2040
2041
2042
2043
2044
2045
2046
2047
2048
2049
2050
The End

Can someone PLEASE assist me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function takes a step argument. The way you have it now in your code the step is 1 (default value). So `range(0,5)` would be 0,1,2,3,4. You should add the factor as the step for incrementing year like this:

```
>>> factor = 5
>>> for year in range(2015,2046,factor):
        print year

2015
2020
2025
2030
2035
2040
2045
```

Comment: Wow! Simple as that?! Thanks a bunch koukouviou!